# Puppeteer getting caught with recaptcha before a site loading

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, recaptcha

I'm using puppeteer to look at car dealerships, and I've been coming across a bunch of dealerships that are instantly marking me for a captcha. I can navigate to these websites perfectly fine just using chrome as normal, but when I run my code it catches it. Any thoughts? Here's an example of one of the websites: [www.vandamautoinc.com](http://www.vandamautoinc.com)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best luck would be this npm plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth

*A plugin for puppeteer-extra to prevent detection.*

Comment: I've tried using stealth to try to avoid this, but it still is sending it to a captcha. Are there any settings or tweaks you'd suggest? Thanks

Comment: Your script should behave like a human. Not too fast by example. Setting a specific user agent is the basics

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution provided by Gilles above is one measure. You can also try some more solution like

1. Using/Changing user-agent with the help of `fingerprint-injector`
2. Use [2Captcha](https://2captcha.com/) to solve captcha whenever they come up and for this purpose, you can also use plugin `puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha`. Adding small snippet for this implementation as one in docs didn't work for me

   ```
   initialize recaptcha plugin similar to how in docs
   puppeteer.use(
     RecaptchaPlugin({
       provider: {
       id: "2captcha",
       token: "2CAPTCHA API KEY",
     },
     visualFeedback: true,
   }));
   ```

Now add the below code wherever the captcha screen appears

```
for (const frame of page.mainFrame().childFrames()) {
  // Attempt to solve any potential captchas in those frames
  const { captchas, filtered, solutions, solved, error } =
  await frame.solveRecaptchas();

  console.log(solved);
}
```